# Generating PDF/A-2 with BIRT

Tags: eclipse, birt, pdfa

How can we generate [PDF/A-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF/A#PDF/A-2) using BIRT?

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

But you can use commercial software to post-process the PDF generated by BIRT.